# Why Directory.GetParent returns for non-path string a Local Temp folder?

Tags: c#

`Directory.GetParent("qwertyuiop")` returns `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Is there any reason for this?

How can I avoid it?
`Directory.GetParent("c:\\")` returns `null`. I expected also null in the case above.

Comment: Because the full path of qwertyuiop is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\qwertyuiop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the full path of qwertyuiop is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\qwertyuiop` - you can't just have a folder with no parent so even though you didn't specify a full path, it has a parent anyway

In a similar fashion, if you did a `File.WriteAllText("a.txt", "some content")` where would you expect the file is written to? It doesn't have a path in the code, just a name, but it will end up on disk somewhere, permissions permitting

For a method that does work like you expect, use `Path.GetDirectoryName` - this performs no inspection of the actual disk, or use the current working directory, it purely uses string logic and will remove anything after the last slash (including the last slash). As your "path" contains no slashes it will reduce it to null

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(@"c:\temp\x"); //c:\temp
Path.GetDirectoryName("x"); //null
```

Answer (score 3):

> Directory.GetParent("qwertyuiop")

This is using a relative path from your present working directory. Detailed explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?view=net-5.0#remarks). You can confirm this with `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`. More information on `GetCurrentDirectory` is found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?view=net-5.0).

Your C drive has no parent (its a root drive) so that is why you getting null for that.

What you could try is always pass in the absolute path. You can generate an absolute path from a method like `Path.GetFullPath`. Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Path_GetFullPath_System_String_System_String_).